# WPF Image : How to download Sourceimage with Proxy Server?

Tags: wpf, image, proxy

In my WPF Application I need to download some images from the internet. It's very easy I just set the URL as Source of the image control and that's all. 
But it's not working anymore when I run my application behind a proxy server!

For a HttpWebRequest I can set a proxy server but it seems it is not possible for an Image control. Do I have to download all the images manually or is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is probably your proxy server, try downloading a tcp monitoring application to the client pc that has to go through the proxy, then watch what tcp traffic is sent when it requests the image url, it is more than likey that the request is being blocked somehow.

Look at how the request is being blocked and talk to the owner of the proxy, there is probably some setting he can turn on/off to allow this to work for you again.